# AWS Lambda: How can I execute RDS Aurora queries as atomic transaction?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have the following Python code in an AWS Lambda function, and I want the queries on an RDS Aurora DB to run atomically, that is, run all or run none. Will the `conn.commit()` statement do that for me? If not how can I accomplish this? `conn` is my DB connection object.

```
# Connect to the DB
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=username,
                       passwd=password, db=db_name,
                       connect_timeout=10)
# Run queries
with conn.cursor() as cur:
    cur.execute("create table some_table_2020 like some_table;")
    cur.execute("insert into some_table_2020 select * from some_table;")
    cur.execute("rename table some_table to some_table_20200629;")
    cur.execute("rename table some_table_2020 to some_table;")
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: Where did `conn` come from? SQLAlchemy, pg8000, something else? That's what manages transactions (or not).

Comment: @kielni, I indicated in my OP that is my DB connection object, but I updated the post just to clarify it. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used `pymysql`, but that's where you should look to find out how to create/commit/rollback transactions (ie group statements to run all or none).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kielni's comment, here's the answer, per [Use Commit and Rollback to Manage MySQL Transactions in Python](http://#%20Connect%20to%20the%20DB%20conn%20=%20pymysql.connect(rds_host,%20user=username,%20passwd=password,%20db=db_name,%20connect_timeout=10)%20#%20Run%20queries%20with%20conn.cursor()%20as%20cur:%20cur.execute(%22create%20table%20some_table_2020%20like%20some_table;%22)%20cur.execute(%22insert%20into%20some_table_2020%20select%20*%20from%20some_table;%22)%20cur.execute(%22rename%20table%20some_table%20to%20some_table_20200629;%22)%20cur.execute(%22rename%20table%20some_table_2020%20to%20some_table;%22)%20conn.commit())

```
# Connect to the DB
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=username,
                       passwd=password, db=db_name,
                       connect_timeout=10)    
try:
    # Run queries
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("create table some_table_2020 like some_table;")
        cur.execute("insert into some_table_2020 select * from some_table;")
        cur.execute("rename table some_table to some_table_20200629;")
        cur.execute("rename table some_table_2020 to some_table;")
    conn.commit()
exception:
    # Failed to commit changes in the DB, do rollback
    conn.rollback()
finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(conn.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```